# How to remove item from sqlite database and recycle view on java android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have tried to initiate the function that removes one of my item from my sqlite database however nothing change. Supposedly there is a button on of the item in my recycle view that acts as a delete button to remove the object from the recycle view. But everytime i click it, nothing changed. Any tips on how to solve it?

this is my recycle view

```
package com.example.myapplication.recyclerview;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.myapplication.DBhelper;
import com.example.myapplication.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class bookingRecycleView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<bookingRecycleView.ViewHolder> {

    // variable for our array list and context
    private ArrayList<Booking> BookingArrayList;
    private Context context;
    DBhelper db;
    String name;
    // constructor
    public bookingRecycleView(ArrayList<Booking> BookingArrayList, Context context) {
        this.BookingArrayList = BookingArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // on below line we are inflating our layout
        // file for our recycler view items.
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rbooking_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // on below line we are setting data 
        // to our views of recycler view item.
        Booking modal = BookingArrayList.get(position);
        holder.tv_name.setText(BookingArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_bookingBategory.setText(BookingArrayList.get(position).getNotes());
        holder.tv_paymentStatus.setText(BookingArrayList.get(position).getBookingCheck());
        holder.button_delete_booking.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),String.valueOf(BookingArrayList.get(position).getBookingid()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            // Set a title for alert dialog
            builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to delete this ?");

            // Ask the final question
            builder.setMessage("Deleted data cannot be undone.");

            // Set the alert dialog yes button click listener
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    db = new DBhelper(context);
                    db.deleteCourse(name);

                }

            });

            // Set the alert dialog no button click listener
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            // Display the alert dialog on interface
            dialog.show();

        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // returning the size of our array list
        return BookingArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // creating variables for our text views.
        public TextView tv_name,tv_bookingBategory,tv_paymentStatus;
        public Button button_delete_booking;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // initializing our text views
            tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nameCrew);
            tv_bookingBategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_crewProgress);
            tv_paymentStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_crewQuantity);
            button_delete_booking = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete_booking);
        }
    }
}
```

dbhelper

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.myapplication.recyclerview.Booking;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final  String DBNAME="database.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "booking";

    public DBhelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super((Context) context,"database.db", null, 1);
    }

    public DBhelper(DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        super((Context) onClickListener,"database.db", null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

         db.execSQL("create table users(username TEXT primary key, password TEXT )");
         db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+"(serviceID INTEGER , name TEXT,notes TEXT,email TEXT,phone TEXT,bookingcheck INTEGER )");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists users");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Boolean insertData(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("username",username);
        values.put("password", password);

        long result  = db.insert("users",null,values);
        if(result==-1)return false;
        else
            return true;




    }

    public void addNewBooking( int serviceID, String name,String notes, String phone, String email, int bookingcheck) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        // on below line we are passing all values
        // along with its key and value pair.

        values.put("serviceID", serviceID);
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("notes", notes);
        values.put("phone", phone);
        values.put("email", email);
        values.put( "bookingcheck", bookingcheck);

        // after adding all values we are passing
        // content values to our table.
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        // at last we are closing our
        // database after adding database.

    }


    public Boolean checkusername(String username){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from users where username = ?", new String[] {username});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            return true;
        }else
            return false;






    }

    public Boolean checkuserpass(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from users where username =? and password =?", new String[] {username,password});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            return true;
        }else
            return false;






    }

    public ArrayList<Booking> readCourses() {
        // on below line we are creating a
        // database for reading our database.
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // on below line we are creating a cursor with query to read data from database.
        Cursor cursorCourses = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

        // on below line we are creating a new array list.
        ArrayList<Booking> courseModalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // moving our cursor to first position.
        if (cursorCourses.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // on below line we are adding the data from cursor to our array list.
                courseModalArrayList.add(new Booking(cursorCourses.getInt(0),
                        cursorCourses.getString(1),
                        cursorCourses.getString(2),
                        cursorCourses.getString(3),
                        cursorCourses.getString(4),
                        cursorCourses.getInt(5)));
            } while (cursorCourses.moveToNext());
            // moving our cursor to next.
        }
        // at last closing our cursor
        // and returning our array list.
        cursorCourses.close();
        return courseModalArrayList;
    }

    public void deleteCourse(String name) {

        // on below line we are creating
        // a variable to write our database.
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // on below line we are calling a method to delete our
        // course and we are comparing it with our course name.
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "name=?", new String[]{name});
        db.close();
    }

}
```

this is my bookingactivity (where the recycleview is shown at)

```
package com.example.myapplication.booking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.myapplication.DBhelper;
import com.example.myapplication.R;
import com.example.myapplication.recyclerview.Booking;
import com.example.myapplication.recyclerview.bookingRecycleView;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    DBhelper db;

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;


    public FloatingActionButton fbtn_createBooking;
    private bookingRecycleView BookingRecycleView;
    private ArrayList<Booking> BookingArrayList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);

        BookingArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        db =new DBhelper(this);
        BookingArrayList = db.readCourses();


        BookingRecycleView = new bookingRecycleView(BookingArrayList, BookingActivity.this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id. recycler_view);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(BookingActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(BookingRecycleView);
        BookingRecycleView.notifyDataSetChanged();



        fbtn_createBooking =findViewById(R.id.fbtn_createBooking);

        fbtn_createBooking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String name;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(BookingActivity.this, AddBookingDetail.class);

                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is you are deleting the data from sqlite but not from *BookingArrayList* you have passed to the adapter. It would be clear if you show us your recycler activity, but i think what you did is fetch data from sqlite and add them to *BookingArrayList*. So when you delete the data you are doing it to the sql DB. you need to also remove it from the array and notify your adapter in order for it to have an effect on your view.

Comment: i have added the code to my bookingactivity which is where the recycle view is shown